# How to add a list of objects as a value for a key in redis using c#?

Tags: c#, redis, servicestack.redis

I have a `Model class -Person` with respective properties.
I want to add a list of person (object) inside a list and set the list as value for a key.
I am using `servicestack.redis` driver.
I saw few examples where `IRedisList<>` has been used.I want to know whether we can insert a `redislist` inside a value parameter because i found that `setentry function`
expects a string  for value parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You can serialize your list (for example JSON string) and add in Redis like normal way, or you can use [ServiceStack.Redis](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Redis) that give you ability to work with POCO objects that you can find StackOverFlow question in this [How to store list element in Redis cache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31955977/how-to-store-list-element-in-redis-cache).