# To store Array of data to Azure Redis Cache

Tags: azure, redis, stackexchange.redis, azure-redis-cache, redis-cache

I want to store the list of data as given below in the Azure redis cache.

```
Designation(KEy)
----------
SoftwareEngineer
Graduate
Trainee
Seniormanager
```

I am new to this Redis cache and learning the stuff and working on. I am able to pass the values in string format where as I face issue while passing the data as a list to the Redis cache. Also how to retrieve the same values using the Key in my API (C# language).

```
Cache.StringSet("Designation", lstitem)
```

Comment: This has been answered in numerous posts, including the one I provided.

Comment: You can try [CachingFramework.Redis](https://github.com/thepirat000/CachingFramework.Redis#cachingframeworkredis) library. Internally uses SE.Redis but provides access to lists, hashes, sets via common `IList<T>`, `IDictionary<T>` interfaces. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31955977/how-to-store-list-element-in-redis-cache/31971420#31971420) answer shows part of the code.